# how to get selected text from html select which dynamically is created?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

this is part of one page that numberOfP is an integer i get from database and is variable.

```
<div>
<%
 string matn = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < numberOfP; i++)
 {
     matn+= " <div class='CMSdiv'>";

     matn += "<input id='Text"+i+"' class='labelhid' type='text' />";
     matn += "<select id='Select"+i+"' class='drophid'>";
     matn += "<option>value= '"+ "خیلی زیاد"+"'>خیلی زیاد" + " <option value= '"+"زیاد'"+">زیاد";
     matn += "</select>";
     matn += "</div>";
     Response.Write(matn);
     matn = "";
 }
%>
</div>
```

Now i want to know in each "CMSdiv" what is text of html select, and then get its value and change 3rd item of my class (which has 3 element) in code behind.

i wrote this code to get a selected item and pour to a label and then got from that label. but it does not work. why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.CMSdiv .drophid').each(function() {
       var selectedText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
       document.getElementById("Labelhid").value = selectedText;
   });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain objective in more detail. Question really doesn't make much sense in context of your server code

Comment: i explained it, is it clear now or you mean some more details?

Comment: There is no `id=Labelhid` in your html. The code you have will only run when page loads and if that element does exist it would only ever get value of the last `<select>`. Still not exactly clear what you are wanting this to do. Code that doesn't work isn't a good substitute for a proper explanation of what it is expected to do

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text of the selected option in a select field with

```
$( "selectElementSelector option:selected" ).text();
```

However from your example all your options are "<option></option>" so they would not have any text.  It also doesn't look like you have a default option selected so it may be null.

To further expand...

```
$('.CMSdiv .drophid').each(function() {
    var selectedText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    console.log("My Selected text is: "+ selectedText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select tag already has an id attribute. Make a while loop and increment inside of it, then break when you no longer find the object:

```
var i = 0;
while (true) {
    var select = document.getElementById('Select' + i);

    if (!select) {break;}
    i++;
}
```

Comment: this part **var select = document.getElementById('Select' + i);** is not usefull because i want its "value", but as i added ".value" it had error and it did not know it.

Comment: I got you to the object. There are no values without valid options, and a .selectedIndex property helps as well.
.value is not available in all browsers, but if there are options in place then this is fairly safe: select.options[select.selectedIndex].value